# Docker busybox tar broken pipe

Tags: tar, docker, busybox, xz

When executing

```
docker run --rm -v ldaps_ldap-config:/volume -v /tmp/tmp.VznAcI3PTA:/backup busybox tar c -Jvf /backup/ldap-config.tar /volume
```

I always get the following output:

```
BusyBox v1.31.0 (2019-07-16 01:13:11 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: xz -d [-cfk] [FILE]...

Decompress FILE (or stdin)

    -d  Decompress
    -c  Write to stdout
    -f  Force
    -k  Keep input files
tar: write error: Broken pipe
```

I use the following versions:

```
Docker version 18.06.3-ce, build d7080c1
BusyBox v1.31.0 (2019-07-16 01:13:11 UTC) multi-call binary.
```

Is this because of busybox or am I doing something wrong?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Busybox container only has the Busybox version of `xz`, [which can only decompress](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/archival/tar.c#n643).

The simplest option here is to use another compressor; the safest best is `-z` instead of `-J` (`gzip`).

Comment: Do you know why this was decided?

Comment: I don’t know whether it was decided explicitly. I suspect it’s a combination of factors: Busybox’s target use cases mean that decompression is sufficient, so expensive compression is a lower priority (which includes `xz`), and the point of the Busybox container image is to contain only Busybox and anything it absolutely needs (which doesn’t include `xz`, apparently, although again I suspect there wasn’t an explicit decision about this).

Comment: I know that you have better things to do with your time, but if you could give a hint I would really appreciated. I am using kubernetes with initContainers, and image image: busybox:1.28, and I am trying to decompress a file "tar -xvf file.tar", but the file never gets decompressed any suggestion?

Comment: @dreamcrash please [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), that way you’ll be able to provide more detail and more people will see your question and hopefully be able to answer it.

Comment: @StephenKitt I will do that thanks